# How can I get a TCP server to send a message back to the client?

Tags: java, android

I'm at a complete loss as to how I can get my server app to send a message back to the client after the client sent a message. My goal is the client sends a message say "Hello" to the server the server receives the message then sends back to the client "hello to you"

my question
How do set up the part of the server sending a message and the client receiving the message?

my server

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Handler updateConversationHandler;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    public String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    private InetAddress serverAddr;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        recieved.setText("");
        if (msg != null){
            recieved.setText(recieved.getText().toString()+"message recieved: "+ msg + “\n”);
        /* SEND MESSAGE */  

        }
    }
}
}
```

my client

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
public String serverIP= "127.0.0.1";
private InetAddress serverAddr;
private Timer myTimer;


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setServerIP();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void sendVerifiedMessage(byte message) throws IOException  {
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
  out.println(message);
/* receive message from client */
    }

    public void run() {
            sendVerifiedMessage(“hello”); 
      }
     }


class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
             connected = false;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
              connected = false;
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Communication between mobile devices is a complex matter unless on a open local network. You might want to look into GCM Google Cloud Messaging or parse.com to send push messages between your devices.

Comment: Thanks, it's running on an open local network. Do you think I could just include the client also being a server and the server also being a client

Comment: Even then I am not sure if it is possible to implement direct communication like this. What I do notice is the ip 127.0.0.1, that is commonly used as the loopback ip, pointing to the device itself, so that so be something different. To get the local ip of the phone go to Settings->About the phone->Status

Comment: I have a settings option in the app the get and set the ip. connecting the devices is not a problem. It's just sending a message back to the client. I don't know how to code that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not dived much into that sort of thing to be honest but if you are looking for a way to pass simple values directly between devices I would again strongly suggest that you look into push notifications from, for example, parse.com. Such a solution would be more battery efficient and work on any network.

Though, it should be possible to do, implementing server/client code on both devices. Sounds like you already managed to send a message in one direction, then to send a response, the exact same method should work the other way around. Cannot see why not.